# Getting Color Values Produced by Dynamic Paint

Tags: python, bmesh, dynamic-paint

I am having trouble with the python code to get the colors of vertices when using Dynamic Paint. If I try painting a cube using the Vertex Paint mode I can get the rgb values of the vertices using the following code, however If I use Dynamic Paint to color the vertices I keep getting "None" for the color layer. Sorry if this is a newbie question but what am I doing wrong here? I thought the color data would be the same whether I used Dynamic Paint or Vertex Paint mode.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
mesh = context.object.data
bm = bmesh.new()

meshes = [o.data for o in scene.objects if o.type == 'MESH']
for mesh in meshes:
    bm.from_mesh(mesh)
    color_layer = bm.loops.layers.color.get("Col")
    print(color_layer)
    if color_layer is None:
        color_layer = bm.loops.layers.color.new("Col")
    for face in bm.faces:
        for loop in face.loops:
            print("Vert:", loop.vert.index)
            print(loop[color_layer])
bm.to_mesh(mesh)
mesh.update()
bm.clear()
```

Comment: Hi did u solve this?